# How to use the value of the forms components which are unchanged using ngModel?

Tags: html, angular, forms, event-handling, mean-stack

I am making a form and want to using the previous values as "value" in the form and by using ngModel dynamically changing some properties but the the field which is not changed by the user, the property is not retaining the previous value even.

```
<form #edit="ngForm" (submit)="editProfile(edit.value)">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username">Username : </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;@{{user.username}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Name :</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;@{{user.name}}
                        <input type="text" name="edit_name" class="form-control" id="name" value={{user.name}} ngModel>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email :</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{user.email}}
                        <input type="text" name="edit_email" class="form-control" id="email" value={{user.email}} ngModel>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="bio">Bio :</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{edit_bio}}
                        <input type="text" name="edit_bio" class="form-control" id="bio" value="Put who you are here!" ngModel>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="gender">Gender</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="gender" name="edit_gender"  ngModel>
                                <option>Male</option>
                                <option>Female</option>
                                <option>Others</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

**In TypeScript File**

```
  edit_name:String='';
  edit_email:String='';
  edit_bio:String='';
  edit_gender:String='';
  user:any={};

ngOnit(){
    this.authService.getuser()
            .subscribe(data=>{
                   this.user=data;
                  }
this.initiateUpdateProfile();
}

initiateUpdateProfile(){
  this.edit_name=this.user.name;
  this.edit_email=this.user.email;
  this.edit_bio='Something you want to tell the world';
  this.edit_gender='Male';
}


  editProfile(e){
console.log(e);
```

}

**Everything is running smoothly** but when i am submitting the form without even touching the form elements than **edit.value** is not even retaining the previous values all it is logging is empty values.

Comment: Try Using [ngModel]="user.name" instead of  value={{user.name}}

Comment: Your code does not make sense.. `ngOnIt` is not a lifecycle hook. It should be `ngOnInit` Setting the value is not gonna work. Or you need reactive forms or you need template driven forms. Read more about it here: https://angular.io/guide/forms and https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: @Chellappan he probably wants two-way binding, so better to use 
 `[(ngModel)]="user.name"` instead of `value={{user.name}}`

Comment: Actually i am displaying the previous value in `value={{user.name}}` and want to update only `[(ngModel)]="edit_name"` only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Name :</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;@{{user.name}}
                        <input type="text" name="edit_name" class="form-control" id="name" [(ngModel)]="edit_name" value={{user.name}}>
                    </div>
```